# Checking Variables In The Constructor

Tags: ruby, variables, constructor

I am learning ruby and know that in other languages I can ensure that variables are not empty when initializing.

How would I do this in Ruby with this example?

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize name 
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to provide a default value? Throw an exception if `nil` is passed? ... can you be a little more specific?

Comment: @LoganSerman I do not want to have a default value, I know how to do that. I want to know if you pass in "" instead of "Paul" how to catch that exception and just make the person re-enter that value until they enter something valid

Comment: Raise an error if there's an invalid parameter.

Comment: @DaveNewton I am still pretty new to Ruby, is there a way to raise an error and make the user correct it and not crash the program

Answer (score 1):

Without setting a default name, and raising an exception if an empty string is sent (not nil) as the argument, then you could raise an exception.

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize name 
    raise "Name can not be an empty String" if name.empty?
    @name = name
  end
end
```

Then if you were to send an empty string you would get an error similar to this:

```
temp.rb:5:in `initialize': Name can not be an empty String (RuntimeError)
    
      from temp.rb:11:in `new'
      from temp.rb:11:in `<main>'

shell returned 1
```

As far as the part of "It makes them enter another name until valid" as you mentioned in another comment... you should let the running code do this.

This is allowing no default, but forcing the user to use something other than an empty string.

```
class PersonNameError < Exception
end
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  def initialize name
    @name = name
  end
end

begin
  print "What is your name? "
  name = gets.chomp
  raise PersonNameError if name.empty?
  person = Person.new(name)
rescue PersonNameError
  if name.empty?
    puts "You can not have a name that is ''"
    retry
  else
    raise
  end
end

puts person.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure people who throw some interesting and much better answers but here's mine.

```
class Person
  attr_reader :name

  # By setting name = nil, we are letting initialize 
  # know that the parameter name may or may not be given.
  def initialize(name = nil) 
    if name
      @name = name
    else
      # This is what you do when the user 
      # did not add a name in the initializer.
      @name = "No name"
    end
  end
end
```

---

So if you do something like

```
person = Person.new
```

the `person` will have the name `No name`.

---

However, if you do

```
person = Person.new("Bob")
```

then `person` will have the name `Bob`.

---

Finally if you set a variable as nil, for example

```
name = nil
```

then pass the `name` into the `new` method

```
Person.new(name)
```

then the `person` will have the name `No name`.

Comment: I am not trying to set a default value. Sorry let me try to make this a little more clear. I am trying to catch when they don't enter a valid name, such as if name = "" instead of something valid like name = "Paul". And if an empty string gets passed in it just keeps making the user re-enter the valid info until they enter something right'

Comment: You would need some sort-of library/database that stores valid names for you to check against. If you decided to not use a library or database, then technically an user can input any word they want.

Comment: Well I don't care if the name = "a", I just want a valid string entered. So I don't think that a library of names is necessary

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what you mean by *empty*. If you mean calling `Person.new` without the `name` variable set like:

```
a = Person.new
```

then you should define a default value for it:

```
def initialize( name = 'Jeffrey' )
    @name = name
end
```

If you mean a `nil` value then you can do:

```
def initialize name 
    @name = (name.nil?) ? 'Jeffrey' : name
end
```

then from here I think you know how to go with empty strings ( `@name = (name == '') ? 'Jeffrey' : name` ) and so on.

Comment: I am not trying to set a default value. Sorry let me try to make this a little more clear. I am trying to catch when they don't enter a valid name, such as if name = "" instead of something valid like name = "Paul". And if an empty string gets passed in it just keeps making the user re-enter the valid info until they enter something right'

Answer (score 0):

Based on what the other answers are doing, the best way IMO is:

```
def initialize(name = 'Default name')
  @name = name
end
```

After your comment...

Is this Rails? That would change a few things. But you can just nil check the value:

```
def initialize(name)
  if name.nil? || name.empty?
    # raise an exception
  else
    @name = name
  end
end
```

If you're using Rails, you can also just use `blank?` which will check both `nil?` and `empty?`.

Comment: I am not trying to set a default value. Sorry let me try to make this a little more clear. I am trying to catch when they don't enter a valid name, such as if name = "" instead of something valid like name = "Paul". And if an empty string gets passed in it just keeps making the user re-enter the valid info until they enter something right'

Comment: Just out of curiosity why is that better than def initialize(name = "Jeff")

Answer (score 0):

Why not accept the user name from within the constructor / initialize method?

```
def initialize name

begin
  while name.empty?
    puts "You can not have a name that is ''"
     print "What is your name? "
     name = gets.chomp
  end
  @name = name
end
end
```